# Get ID from URL, save it into variable and use in href, all using PHP

Tags: php, html, variables, url

In short I want to get the ID from an URL, save it into a variable and represent it in href link opened via `img` tag, all using PHP.

My URL is: test.php?id=123

I want to save the ID into the variable `ticket_dym_id` used in href.

My code:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
$ticket_dym_id = $id;

<html>
  <title>title</title>
</html>
<center>
<a href="test2?id=&lt;$ticket_dym_id&gt;"><img="img.jpg"/></a>

</center>
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php `echo` :

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$ticket_dym_id = $id;
?>

<html>
  <title>title</title>
</html>
<center>
  <a href="test2?id=<?php echo $ticket_dym_id; ?>">
</center>
```

[echo documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.echo.php)

Comment: That still won't work if you don't close the starting `<?php` in time.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i tried it bu it doesnt show the id still.

Comment: Moved the php closing tag to output the html, thanks to @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Tried it after your answer, it still shows $ticket_dym_id; and not the id

Comment: Personally I find having `<?php ....?>` inside a string very questionable. I would keep it cleaner and replace the whole line with: `<?php echo '<a href="test2?id='.$ticket_dym_id.'">link</a>'; ?>`. Other solution are possible, of course.

Comment: I have it as <?php echo '<a href="test2?id='.$ticket_dym_id.'"><img src="img.jpg"/></a>  <br /> ';?> and still doest show the id on image url

Comment: your closing html tag </html>  is also in the wrong place needs to be after </center>

Comment: Also noticed missing closing tag for the anchor </a> your html needs to be <html><title>title<title><center><a href="test2?id=<?php echo $ticket_dym_id; ?>">linkname</a></center></html>

Comment: Oh yea right, corrected it, but anything still didnt get the id from url :/